# Winforms Adding and remove UserControls

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

So I have an application that uses a **single master form** with a menu along the left-side of the form.

On the right-side I have a `panel` that acts as a placeholder for any `UserControl` I have created.

Each time a user `clicks` on a menu item, the related `UserControl` will display using code like this:

```
//Display UserControl first
ucMyUserControl uc = new ucMyUserControl ();
uc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
pnlContainer.Controls.Add(uc);
```

Is there a better way than to just copy and paste this for each button or whenever I want to display a `UserControl`. Should I be creating a function to call each time and just passing the name of the `UserControl` I want to use?

Maybe I've got it all wrong in the first place with the way I'm using it - I'm new to this concept and just trying things out.

Comment: You can use a Tab panel with the Tabs hidden. The buttons just needs to change the Tab index. If the buttons are in an stack panel and are generated dynamically, you can use the button index to change the tab index. Sorry about english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, don't repeat yourself.  Write DRY code with a helper method.  It could look like this:

```
public void ShowPage(UserControl uc) {
    while (pnlContainer.Controls.Count > 0) pnlContainer.Controls[0].Dispose();
    uc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    pnlContainer.Controls.Add(uc);
}
```

And now you simply call `ShowPage(new ucMyUserControl());`

Note that the quirky looking while-loop is important, you don't just want to use the Controls.Remove() method.  Disposing controls that you remove is very important, if you don't then they'll live forever and ultimately crash your program.

Comment: I think that to DRY he should use a TabPanel with hidden TabItems. Also, using this approach, he can use the designer.

Comment: Meh, user controls scale a wholeheckofalot better and are certainly well supported by the designer.

Comment: Designer in the main window, not in the control itself. Also, the TabPanel don't need to dispose all time, so its a lot faster, but can consume more ram. But, the user alway prefer fast reactions.

Comment: To clarify my comment, i meant use the TabControl with UserControls (with Dock.Fill) in the TabItems.